# How do I to create my own "tabs" in Mentor Pads Professional?

Tags: mentor-pads

Is there a way to build a new tab (like "File", "Edit", "View", "Tools") at the top?

Comment: What does it say in the product documentation on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I asked our layouter. It is indeed possible.

**scripst.ini** tells Mentor Pads Pro which scripts to run on startup.

**DxMenu.vbs** creates additional menu entries *"BEH"* and *"MORENO"*.

- *"BEH"* contains commands *"Variant PDFs"* and *"Add Prj Path"*
- *"MORENO"* contains command *"Check Rippers"*

The root path for all these files is in our case:
`I:\CAD\Mentor_VX\WDIR_Global\WDIR_PADSProVX_2_11\`

*scripts.ini*

```ini
[Viewdraw]
script#0=DxMenu.vbs
```

*DxMenu.vbs*

```vb
'==========================================================================
' DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTY:  Unless otherwise agreed in writing,
' Mentor Graphics software and associated files are provided "as is"
' and without warranty.  Mentor Graphics has no obligation to support
' or otherwise maintain software.  Mentor Graphics makes no warranties,
' express or implied with respect to software including any warranty
' of merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
'
' LIMITATION OF LIABILITY: Mentor Graphics is not liable for any property
' damage, personal injury, loss of profits, interruption of business, or for
' any other special, consequential or incidental damages, however caused,
' whether for breach of warranty, contract, tort (including negligence),
' strict liability or otherwise. In no event shall Mentor Graphics'
' liability exceed the amount paid for the product giving rise to the claim.
'==========================================================================
  Dim fso
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Dim cmd, cmd2, cmd3 
  
  Dim wdirVar, wdirPaths, VariantPDFs
  wdirVar = Scripting.GetEnvVariable("WDIR_PADSProVX_2_11")
    
  wdirPaths = Split(wdirVar, ";")

  Dim i, count, filePathName
  count = UBound(wdirPaths, 1)

  For i = 0 to count
 
    If (fso.FileExists(wdirPaths(i) & "\runSchematicPDFs.vbs")) Then
      cmd = "run " & wdirPaths(i) & "\runSchematicPDFs.vbs"
    End If

    If (fso.FileExists(wdirPaths(i) & "\runAddPrjPath.vbs")) Then
      cmd2 = "run " & wdirPaths(i) & "\runAddPrjPath.vbs"
    End If
    
    If (fso.FileExists(wdirPaths(i) & "\tools\CheckRippers_07.efm")) Then
      cmd3 = "run " & wdirPaths(i) & "\tools\CheckRippers_07.efm"
    End If

    'msgbox(wdirPaths(i) & "\runSchematicPDFs.vbs")  ' used for debug only
  Next

' Add as 10th menu in Sheet Menu Bar
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Session Menu - no Entry at the Moment
'
Set menu = CommandBars("Main Menu Bar").Controls.Add(cmdControlPopup,,,10)
menu.Caption = "BEH"
'Set button = menu.Controls.Add  ' Add a button to the menu
'button.Caption = "Design-Info"
'button.Target = ScriptEngine
'button.ExecuteMethod = "run_exe"

Set menu = CommandBars("Main Menu Bar").Controls.Add(cmdControlPopup,,,11)
menu.Caption = "MORENO"

' Document Menu - available if Schematics are open
'
Set menu = CommandBars("Sheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add(cmdControlPopup,,,10)
menu.Caption = "&BEH"
Set button = menu.Controls.Add  ' Add a button to the menu
button.Caption = "Variant PDFs"
button.OnAction = cmd

Set button = menu.Controls.Add  ' Add a button to the menu
button.Caption = "Add Prj Path"
button.OnAction = cmd2


Set menu = CommandBars("Sheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add(cmdControlPopup,,,11)
menu.Caption = "&MORENO"
Set button = menu.Controls.Add  ' Add a button to the menu
button.Caption = "Check Rippers"
button.OnAction = cmd3
'----------

Scripting.DontExit = True
```

*runAddPrjPath.vbs*

```vb
 '==========================================================================
 ' DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTY:  Unless otherwise agreed in writing,
 ' Mentor Graphics software and associated files are provided "as is"
 ' and without warranty.  Mentor Graphics has no obligation to support
 ' or otherwise maintain software.  Mentor Graphics makes no warranties,
 ' express or implied with respect to software including any warranty
 ' of merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
 '
 ' LIMITATION OF LIABILITY: Mentor Graphics is not liable for any property
 ' damage, personal injury, loss of profits, interruption of business, or for
 ' any other special, consequential or incidental damages, however caused,
 ' whether for breach of warranty, contract, tort (including negligence),
 ' strict liability or otherwise. In no event shall Mentor Graphics'
 ' liability exceed the amount paid for the product giving rise to the claim.
 '==========================================================================
 '
 ' This script fills any "PrjPath"-Property value on the active Schematic with the current Project-Path 
 '
 '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub addPrjPath()
  Dim dxdApp
  Set dxdApp = GetObject(, "ViewDraw.Application")
  Set vdview = dxdApp.ActiveView
   ' Get the project directory path
  sProjectPath = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectPath
  
  Dim VDM_COMP, VD_ALL, VDM_ALL
  VDM_COMP = 128
  VDM_ALL = 16384
  VD_ALL = 0

  For Each Comp In vdview.Query(VDM_COMP, VD_ALL)
    For Each CompAttr in Comp.Attributes
      If CompAttr.name = "PrjPath" Then 
        Set CompAttr = Comp.AddAttribute("PrjPath" & "=" & sProjectPath, PropXLoc,PropYLoc,0)   
        CompAttr.Selected = False
      End If
    Next
  Next
  Set CurBlock = vdview.Block
End Sub

Call addPrjPath
```

*runSchematicPDFs.vbs*

```vb
 '==========================================================================
 ' DISCLAIMER OF WARRANTY:  Unless otherwise agreed in writing,
 ' Mentor Graphics software and associated files are provided "as is"
 ' and without warranty.  Mentor Graphics has no obligation to support
 ' or otherwise maintain software.  Mentor Graphics makes no warranties,
 ' express or implied with respect to software including any warranty
 ' of merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
 '
 ' LIMITATION OF LIABILITY: Mentor Graphics is not liable for any property
 ' damage, personal injury, loss of profits, interruption of business, or for
 ' any other special, consequential or incidental damages, however caused,
 ' whether for breach of warranty, contract, tort (including negligence),
 ' strict liability or otherwise. In no event shall Mentor Graphics'
 ' liability exceed the amount paid for the product giving rise to the claim.
 '==========================================================================
 '
 ' This script creates Variant Schematic PDF's and names the files by VM Name and Number
 ' PDF's store in ./SA-PDFs directory of the Project
 '
 '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub createPDF(PDF_name, VariantName)
   If Application.ActiveView is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please open a schematic and retry."
    Exit Sub
  End If
 
 
' The Viewlogic.Exec object is used to run programs
  Set oExec = CreateObject("Viewlogic.Exec")
 
' Set the working directory, in case the program creates log files.
 ' Run the program in the project directory
  oExec.WorkingDirectory = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectPath

 ' Get the project directory path
  sProjectPath = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectPath

 ' Get the .prj path
  sProjectFilePath = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectFilePath
 
  ' Get the schematic name
  sSchematicName = Application.ActiveView.TopBlock.GetName(SHORT_NAME)

 ' Get SDD_HOME
  sSDD_HOME = Scripting.GetEnvVariable("SDD_HOME")
 
' Usage: sch2pdf -project <project file>
'         [-eevm <fileName>] [-a <outFileName>] [-h|-help|-?][-c <colorCode>]
'         [-g* <global override>][-i <hyperlink>] [-l <level>] [-o <order>] [-s]
'
'         [-p] [-v] [-u <name>] [-schematic <name>]
'                -h|-help|-?: print this info
'                -project: project file
'                -eevm: variant manager file name
'                -a: Overrides default output filename of <design>.pdf
'                -d: Disable compression
'                -i: Interpret component attribute values as potential URLs
'                -s: Start Acrobat viewer and display output file
'                -f: Create document listing available fonts
'                -p: Add popup menu on components
'                -v: Visible hyperlinks
'                -schematic: Schemat name
'                -e: Use exclusion info
'                -udx: Use DxD font mapping
'                -u <font>: Use strokes as is
'                 Available fonts:
'                 "All" uses strokes for every font
'                color_code:
'                        0:      Black on white, suppress black text
'                        1:      Color on white
'                        2:      Color on black
'                        3:      Black on white, print black text
'                        4:      Color on white  print color text
'                hyperlink: Component attribute names whose values will be checked as potential legal URLs
'                level: Attribute to stop descending composite symbols (specify multiple levels separately)
'                order: Component attribute names whose values override sheet order (use with Scout)
'                Global overrides: Override memory allocation defaults.
'                     Use only on very large designs which do not otherwise complete
 
' Build the command line string:
  sCmdline = sSDD_HOME & "\wv\win64\bin\sch2pdf.exe "
  sCmdLine = sCmdLine & "-project " & chr(34) & sProjectFilePath & chr(34)
  'Vwd_V1_MA.vwd
  If VariantName = "MASTER" Then
    ' Skip the VM File Attribute
  Else
    sCmdLine = sCmdLine & " -eevm " & chr(34) & sProjectPath & "\Vwd_" & VariantName & "_MA.vwd" & chr(34)
'    sCmdLine = sCmdLine & " -eevm " & chr(34) & sProjectPath & "\Vwd_" & VariantName & "_RemNK.vwd" & chr(34)
  End If
  'sCmdline = sCmdline & " -c 0 -l STD -udx -p -e -i Datasheet -a "  'enable for PDF's with Datasheetlink and all BLOCKS
  sCmdline = sCmdline & " -c 3 -l STD -udx -p -e -schematic " & chr(34) & sSchematicName & chr(34) & " -a "  'PDF's without Datasheetlink and without Blocksheets
  sCmdline = sCmdline & chr(34) & sProjectPath &  "\Output-Doc\" & PDF_name & ".pdf" & chr(34)
  'MsgBox sCmdLine

' Prepare the Output Dir
'  Dim fso
'  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'  If Not fso.FolderExists(sProjectPath & "\Output-Doc") Then
'    fso.CreateFolder(sProjectPath & "\Output-Doc\")
'  End If 


 ' Run the command line - 0 no black CMD Window pops up
  oExec.Run sCmdline, 0
 
' Do not try to reuse this object
  Set oExec = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub cycleVariants()
  Dim csvLine, csvVars
  csvLine = chr(34) & "Part Number" & chr(34) & "," & chr(34) & "Ref" & chr(34)
  Dim vm_visible    'remember the visibility of VM
  Dim dxdApp, vmaddin
  'Set dxdApp = GetObject(, "ViewDraw.Application")
  Set dxdApp = Application
  Set vmaddin = dxdApp.Addins("Variant Manager")
  vm_visible = vmaddin.Visible
   ' Get the project directory path
  sProjectPath = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectPath
 
 
  If vmaddin Is Nothing Then
    Set vmaddin = dxdApp.Addins.Add("MGCVARIANTGUI.MGCVariantGUICtrl.1", "Variant Manager", "")
  End If
  vmaddin.Visible = True

  Set vmbom = vmaddin.Control.VariantGuiApplication.BOM
  Set vmdoc = vmaddin.Control.VariantGuiApplication.VMDocument
  Set vmApp = vmaddin.Control.VariantGuiApplication
  Set vmvars = vmdoc.Variants("")
  iVariantDefinition = 0
  sMsg = "List of Variant Definitions:" & VbCrLf

' Get 1st Header Symbol Name
'  Dim BorderSymbol
'  Set BorderSymbols = vmdoc.GetBorderSymbols
 
    Dim PDFname
    For Each vmvar In vmvars
      csvVars = csvVars & "," & chr(34) & vmvar.Name & chr(34)
    
      iVariantDefinition = iVariantDefinition + 1
      SMsg = sMsg & "Variant Definition " & CStr(iVariantDefinition) & ": " & vmvar.Name & VbCrLf
      vmbom.Add vmvar.Name
      vmApp.GenerateVariantView vmvar.Name
    
        'PDFname = "Schematic-" & vmvar.Name & "-" & vmvar.Number
        PDFname = vmvar.Name & "_SCH"
        Call createPDF(PDFname, vmvar.Name)
        'msgbox("wait")
   Next
   'csvLine = csvLine & csvVars
    'MsgBox(csvLine)
    
    'Dim iCompModTotal
    'iCompModTotal = vmdoc.ComponentModifications.Count
    
    'Dim fso
    'Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Dim oCsvTextStream
    'Set oCsvTextStream = fso.CreateTextFile(sProjectPath &  "\var_report.csv", True)
    'oCsvTextStream.WriteLine(csvLine)
    
    'Dim cmpLine
    
    'For Each comp In vmdoc.Components
'    csvLine = chr(34) & comp.OriginalPartNumber & chr(34) & "," & chr(34) & comp.Name & chr(34)
'   
'       Dim matchCnt
' 
'    For Each vmvar In vmvars   
'       matchCnt = 0
'       For Each compMod In vmdoc.ComponentModifications
'           If compMod.Component.Name = comp.Name then
'               If compMod.Variant.Name = vmvar.Name then
'                   If compMod.Operation = 2  Then ' Part Number Override
'                       csvLine = csvLine & "," & chr(34) & compMod.NewPartNumber & chr(34)
'                       matchCnt =  matchCnt + 1
'                   ElseIf compMod.Operation = 1 Then  ' unplace
'                       csvLine = csvLine & "," & chr(34) & "<unplaced>" & chr(34)
'                       matchCnt =  matchCnt + 1
'               Else
'                 csvLine = csvLine & "," & chr(34) & chr(34)
'                 matchCnt =  matchCnt + 1
'               End If
'             End If
'           End If
'          Next
'          If matchCnt = 0 then
'           csvLine = csvLine & "," & chr(34) & chr(34)
'         End If
'       Next
'      oCsvTextStream.WriteLine(csvLine)
'   Next
    
'   oCsvTextStream.Close

   vmApp.ResetView
   ' Get the .prj name
     sProjectName = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectName
  
      'PDFname = "Schematic-MASTER-XXXX"
      PDFname = sProjectName & "_MASTER_SCH"
      Call createPDF(PDFname, "MASTER")
    
      'BOM
    '  vmbom.Add("All")
    '  vmbom.IncludeMaster = True
    '  vmbom.OutputPath = sProjectPath &  "\Output-Doc\"
    '  vmbom.Type = 0 ' Partlist
      'vmbom.Type = 1 ' RefDeslist
      'vmbom.Format = 1 ' formated Text
      'vmbom.Format = 2 ' HTML
      'vmbom.Format = 3 ' deliminated Text
    '  vmbom.Format = 4 ' Excel
    '  vmbom.execute()
      
    'MsgBox sMsg
    vmaddin.Visible = vm_visible
  
    Dim WshShell
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
    Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("explorer " & sProjectPath &  "\Output-Doc\")

    Set WshShell = Nothing 
End Sub

Private Sub renameXLS()
  If Application.ActiveView is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please open a schematic and retry."
    Exit Sub
  End If
'The Viewlogic.Exec object is used to run programs
  Set oExec = CreateObject("Viewlogic.Exec")

' Set the working directory, in case the program creates log files.
 ' Run the program in the project directory
  oExec.WorkingDirectory = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectPath
    
 ' Get the project directory path
  sProjectPath = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectPath
    'MsgBox "sProjectPath:" & sProjectPath
    
 ' Get the .prj path
  sProjectFilePath = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectFilePath
    'MsgBox "sProjectFilePath:" & sProjectFilePath
    
  ' Get the schematic name
  sSchematicName = Application.ActiveView.TopBlock.GetName(SHORT_NAME)

 ' Get SDD_HOME
  sSDD_HOME = Scripting.GetEnvVariable("SDD_HOME")
  
 ' Get the .prj name
     sProjectName = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectName
  
  Dim fso, folder, file
  Dim foldername
  
  foldername = sProjectPath & "\Output-Doc\"
  'MsgBox "foldername:" & foldername
  
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
  Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderName)  
  
  For each file In folder.Files  
     If instr(file, "_master.xls") > 0 THEN
       file.name = replace(file.name, "_master.xls", sProjectName & "_MASTER.xls")
      'MsgBox file.name
     End IF
  Next  
  
  For each file In folder.Files  
     If instr(file, ".xls") > 0 THEN
       file.name = replace(file.name, ".xls", "_STL.xls")
      'MsgBox file.name
     End IF
  Next   
     
End Sub

Private Sub CleanOrCreateOutputFolder()
'The Viewlogic.Exec object is used to run programs
  Set oExec = CreateObject("Viewlogic.Exec")

' Set the working directory, in case the program creates log files.
 ' Run the program in the project directory
  oExec.WorkingDirectory = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectPath
    
 ' Get the project directory path
  sProjectPath = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectPath
    'MsgBox "sProjectPath:" & sProjectPath
    
 ' Get the .prj path
  sProjectFilePath = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectFilePath
    'MsgBox "sProjectFilePath:" & sProjectFilePath
    
  ' Get the schematic name
  sSchematicName = Application.ActiveView.TopBlock.GetName(SHORT_NAME)

 ' Get SDD_HOME
  sSDD_HOME = Scripting.GetEnvVariable("SDD_HOME")
  
 ' Get the .prj name
     sProjectName = Application.GetProjectData.GetProjectName
     
' Prepare the Output Dir
  Dim fso
  Dim outputFolder
  
  outputFolder = sProjectPath & "\Output-Doc"
  
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If fso.FolderExists(sProjectPath & "\Output-Doc\") Then
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(outputFolder)
    'Output Verzeichnis löschen, egal ob darin Dateien vorhanden sind oder nicht.
    'fso.DeleteFolder outputFolder, True
    'MsgBox outputFolder
    
    'Alle Dateien im Output Verzeichnis löschen
    'for each f in folder.Files
    'On Error Resume Next
    '  name = f.name
    '  f.Delete True
    '  If Err Then
    '    WScript.Echo "Error deleting:" & Name & " - " & Err.Description
    '  Else
    '    WScript.Echo "Deleted:" & Name
    '  End If
    '  On Error GoTo 0
    'Next
  End If
  
   ' Prepare the Output Dir
  'Dim fso
  
  'Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  
   If Not fso.FolderExists(sProjectPath & "\Output-Doc") Then
    fso.CreateFolder(sProjectPath & "\Output-Doc\")
  End If 
  
  ' Do not try to reuse this object
  Set oExec = Nothing
    
End Sub

Call CleanOrCreateOutputFolder
Call cycleVariants
'Call renameXLS
```

These VB scripts look like they could be cleaned up a bit. But perhaps it might help you getting started.